# Making message load from db with socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, express

I am working on a project with node, express, mongo and socket.io. I am successful in making a socket connection and saving the message to the db. what i like to achieve now is that when someone joins in a discussion that he gets to see all the previous messages. And here is where i hit a roadblock.

my code of the route file is the following:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {

var topicId = req.params.id;
console.log('Logging topic id: ' + topicId);

// find one single topic based on id
Topic.findById(topicId, function(err, topic)
{
   if(err)
   {    
       console.log('There was no topic with this ID');
      return next(err)
   }
   else
   {
      console.log('Whoop whoop we found a topic matching the requested ID');

      Comment.find().where("commentTopicId", topicId).exec(function(err,  comments) 
     {

      res.render('topicdetail', { topic: topic , comments: comments } );
      console.log("Logging data topic: " + topic);
      console.log("Loggin data title out db: " + topic.topicTitle);

      console.log("Logging data comment: " + comments);
      console.log("Logging error: " + err);

     });

    }

  });

  });
```

the second query in the else statement works cause i get the topics detail page with the necessary info but the console log of comments returns a null

so i am not sure where i went wrong with my code.

Comment: what does your front end look like?

Comment: i not yet made the for loop in the view for the comments i first wanted to get the data in the console log (http://qa-forum.herokuapp.com/topicdetail/555241db169ed40300991166)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you using the find instead of where first?

```
Comment.find({commentTopicId: topic._id}).exec(function(err,  comments) {
  res.send(200, comments);
}
```